# how to select an item from generic list by linq

Tags: c#, .net

I have a LINQ query which contains a method GetInstanceForDatabase()

```
principlesList.Select(p => p.GetInstanceForDatabase()).ToList()
```

where

```
List<PrincipleInstance>() principlesList = ...
// (contains list of principle like "Manual Trades", "OPM", "Flora")
```

`GetInstanceForDatabase()` is a method  which takes all other info about a principle (like manual trades).

My problem is that I want to sort out only principle like only "Manual Trades".

I want to put a `where` clause. I tried but it is fails.

Comment: How is it failing? Unintended results or some exception being thrown?

Comment: Perhaps you should post your attempt to use the Where method, so we can see where you went wrong and correct you. Help us help you; most of us don't have time to write answers that would cover every possible thing you could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To get a single item use:

```
query.First(x => x.property == "Manual Trades");
// or
query.FirstOrDefault(x => x.property == "Manual Trades");
```

Comment: well query is working ... one more point is that                 here is the complete method                                                                    DataBaseFacade.Instance.UpdatePrinciples(ApplicationData.Instance.ProfessionalName,RunningUser.Instance.UserData.UserName,          principlesList.Select(p => p.GetInstanceForDatabase()).Where(p => p.Name=="Manual Trades").ToList(),dateTime,dbSavedCallback);                           i just want to see **"principlesList.Select(p => p.GetInstanceForDatabase()).Where(p => p.Name=="Manual Trades").ToList()"** in add watch .is there any way

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = p.GetInstanceForDatabase().where(x => x.propertyName == "Manual Trades").ToList();
```

I'm sure you're GetInstanceForDatabase needs to return your collection that you then filter for the 'Manual Trades' but I can't really tell how you get your list of PrincipalInstances from the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax of using `Where` in `LINQ`

```
principlesList.Select(p => p.GetInstanceForDatabase()).Where(p => p.SomeProperty == "SomeValue").ToList();
```

Comment: thanks Haris Hasan .. at least i have got an query which has not error , i am trying to implement it